# Как в pycharm добавить vcs в главное меню?

Tags: pycharm

Как в пайчарм добавить vcs меню чтобы было так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данный момент у меня так:
[image: arm]

То есть я хочу чтобы в панели меню была надпись VCS как на первом скрине.Как это можно сделать ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По видимому кто то отредактировал Ваше меню.

Оно редактируется в File - Settings (**Ctrl+Alt+S**).

[image: Скриншот]

*Самый простой вариант:* Нажмите кнопку [**Restore default**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2019.2/menus-and-toolbars-appearance-settings.html?utm_campaign=PY&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_content=2019.2)

Answer (score 0):

Лучший ответ на русском пространстве интернета это - купи Professional ed.)) На втором месте - кто то отредактировал ваше меню (при том, что кроме вас этого сделать скорее всего никто не мог, а сами вы не знаете как это делать, иначе бы вас тут не было) На третьем месте пожалуй оставлю свой вариант - File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/Appearance там снимаем галочку напротив Merge main menu with window title
на всякий случай добавлю, что все это работает для community edition